# How does Firebase command-line login work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am trying out Firebase / Firestore. When I run the command-line `firebase login` in a Linux terminal, I am redirected to the typical Google login web-site but with an additional Firebase-logo. After login on that web-site, I have to enable various features and permissions for Firebase to access my Google account.

Then the `firebase` program on my local Linux PC knows that I have logged in to my Google account. Even after I restart the computer, the `firebase` program is apparently still logged in to my Google account.

How does this work behind the scenes? Is my Google account password stored on my local PC somewhere, since `firebase` remains logged in to the account? Doesn't that cause a security risk?

Thanks!

Comment: Your auth data is stored in `~/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, passwords are never stored like that.  That would be incredibly unsafe.  The CLI is storing a special token that gives access to parts of the account that you authorized in the web browser.  That token is valid until something invalidates it, or you sign out by running `firebase logout`.  It's similar to the way most auth systems work that allow an individual to stay signed in for long periods of time without reauthenticating.

If you want to see exactly what the CLI is doing, it's all [open source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed reply! So the token stored on my local PC only gives access to those parts of Firebase that I granted access to on the Google web-site. The token cannot be used to access other parts of my Google account, such as e-mail, Drive, YouTube, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: No, the CLI cannot read any of your data that you didn't explicitly grant.